# Missing .dll files c++

Tags: c++

I am coding in c++ visual studios express 2010 and have been creating a program.  I thought it would run fine, but when other people try to run it, they just get missing .dll error.  I know that I probably am not obtaining the .exe correctly, but I don't know what to do.

Can someone tell me how to compile CLR console applications so that they include these libraries?

The .dll file is MSVCR100D.dll and I don't know if there are more of them.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have build the application in Debug mode. You need to rebuild it in Release mode, and then distribute.

[image: Debug mode - Visual Studio]